# How to compare a python datetime date with a Mysql column date?

Tags: python, mysql

**Environment:**

Windows 10

Python 3.7

Mysql 1:10.1.44-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

**Problem:**

I need to count the number of rows between 2 dates from a Mysql table. The 2 dates are made with python code. And the column date in my MySQL table is type 'text' and values look like this: "10/06/2020 18:50:17"

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
previous_week_date= now - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
print(now)
print(previous_week_date)
sql_query = f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM W551je5v_phonebot_actions WHERE id_client={id_client} AND  \ 
platform='myplatform' AND type_action='message_sent' AND date BETWEEN CAST ('{previous_week_date}' AS DATE) AND CAST ('{now}' AS DATE)"
    
mycursor.execute (sql_query )
result= mycursor.fetchone ()
```

I get this error output:

```
2020-08-21 19:34:50.990393
2020-08-14 19:34:50.990393
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1584 (42000): Incorrect parameters in the call to stored function 'CAST'
```

So I guess I need an MYSQL function which will convert the value of Mysql column date text in date format, but I have no idea how to do that. The answers I found here and in Google don't respond to my need.

Comment: It is a big mystake to store dates in varchar columns in a DB. You should use the date or datetime type

Comment: Yes, I know. But this is like this and I can't change the type of column or I will risk damaging all the system. So I need a solution. It is a nightmare for me now. Please help.